# Javascript Animation - SVG shape disappearing

Tags: javascript, svg

I am just getting into JS, so I may be missing something. I am trying to animate an SVG rectangle with a mouseover so that the shape appears to be 'fleeing' the mouse. When I try to change x and y by adding to them, the shape disappears. If I subtract, it behaves as expected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
HTML
     <svg width="1200" height="600">
         <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" id="firstShape" onmouseover="moveShape(firstShape);">               
     </svg>
Javascript
     function moveShape(obj) {
                var newX = obj.getAttribute("x") + 5;
                var newY = obj.getAttribute("y") + 5;           
                obj.setAttribute("x", newX);
                obj.setAttribute("y", newY);
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are strings, and Javascript is very sloppy about the way it handles strings and numbers.

What you were actually doing is adding "5" to "100" and getting "1005" as a result.

If you convert the attributes to integers before modifying them, then your code will work fine.

```js
function moveShape(obj) {
  var newX = parseInt(obj.getAttribute("x")) + 5;
  var newY = parseInt(obj.getAttribute("y")) + 5;
  obj.setAttribute("x", newX);
  obj.setAttribute("y", newY);
}
```

```html
<svg width="1200" height="600">
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" id="firstShape" onmouseover="moveShape(firstShape);">               
</svg>
```

Comment: @user3602839 No problem :-) By the way, use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` if there's any chance that these coordinates might not be integers.